# Lossless and Identical way - BufferedImage to File

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel, bufferedimage, lossless-compression

I have a `BufferedImage` Object which I have manimulated it pixels (The numeric values). Now how can I save it to a file - preferable JPEG file - without any change in pixels values???

Comment: Without any further change, or reversing the changes you have made?

Comment: JPEG isn't lossless, so you're going to need to use a different format (and possibly have a huge file if it has a lot of colors) or just put up with the minor changes JPEG makes to your image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and use `ImageIO.write( image, "some lessless format", new FileOutputStream(...) );`.

Comment: I need the output to be 8-bit grayscale JPEG! and I think ImageIO doesn't work well with JPEGs!

Comment: Why should ImageIO not work well with JPEGs? It's true that sometimes there problems with CMYK encoded JPEG but there are easy ways around that if you skip the ImageIO class and use the slightly more low level api. And if you use RGB or greyscale images, the CMYK problems should not apply. If you need something special you could also look into [Java Advanced Imaging API](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/)